# Regular Expression to find if a function string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a better way to find in a function string in regular expression.

Ex ... If a string contains like a function expression like **count("alerts")** , then the regular expression should return [0] -> "count" and the parameters in -> [1]

Comment: Now are you looking to _parse_ JavaScript code?

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like how knockout works. It used data-bind attribute to parse a string and execute a function. For example: data-bind="text:getCount('alert')"

Answer (score 0):

Does not look to be a good idea, but who am I to judge. It should work with a function with any kind of parameter. One parameter only. Didn't think of any edge cases.

```
\w+\(("?\w+"?)\)
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like how knockout works. It used data-bind attribute to parse a string and execute a function. For example: data-bind="text:getCount('alert')". Do you think that is not a good idea? I am thinking of a better solution

Comment: You can spike with regex, but I think that in the long run you should be looking at some kind of tokenization mechanism

Comment: Could you give me more references on tokenization mechanism? Really interested to get an idea of what is it?

Comment: Take a look at the question I asked a long time ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444497/whats-needed-for-nlp. That touches a little bit of what you are looking for. You probably don't need that much, but you want you can down the rabbit hole. If I were you I would stay with the regex until I knew exactly what I was doing.

Comment: Sure. I will stay with regex for now. This is just for a proof of concept which i am developing.

Comment: I'm sorry buddy, but you will have to work on that yourself. If you have questions we can try to help.